# Mismatch between my kinesis data and s3 data. Why is this?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

The data when I get-records on my kinesis:

```
aws kinesis get-shard-iterator --shard-id shardId-000000000000 --shard-iterator-type TRIM_HORIZON --stream-name <kinesis_stream> --profile sandbox
aws kinesis get-records --shard-iterator <some long iterator> --profile sandbox
```

looks like this:

```
{
            "SequenceNumber": "49597879057469488670276149632780729413492497034093002754",
            "ApproximateArrivalTimestamp": 1563920035.139,
            "Data": "<some very long data encoded/encrypted/",
            "PartitionKey": "84b15621-f823-43f6-acc7-069a2acfdea1"
        }
```

This kinesis is linked to a kinesis firehouse which is linked to s3 but my bucket objects look like this:

```
{"type":"DatabaseActivityMonitoringRecords","version":"1.0","databaseActivityEvents":"<some long event encrypted/encoded>"}
```

Why is there this mismatch? Where is the transformation from kinesis to s3 taking place? What is get-records actually getting me? What does the kinesis data represent? What does my s3 events represent?

For context, I am using an aurora database with database activity stream connected to kinesis -> kinesis firehouse -> s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer I posted here:
[How is data in kinesis decrypted before hitting s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173084/how-is-data-in-kinesis-decrypted-before-hitting-s3)

These 2 questions are very similar.

Why is there this mismatch?

- All data in the Kinesis stream are base64 encoded. So base on the client you are using to view it, you may either see the encoded or decoded version. Ie. Node library will decode it for you. AWS CLI does not decode the message

Where is the transformation from kinesis to s3 taking place?

- The internal AWS event handlers will perform the decoding before storing it into S3. You can't see it, but essentially its just a lambda moving data from Kinesis -> S3 for you.

What is get-records actually getting me?

- It gives you your data, plus information on "where" it is in the Kinesis stream.

What does the kinesis data represent? 
What does my s3 events represent?

- They should both represent your data. Kinesis responses come with additional decoration to identify where it is in the stream so you can go back and find it later. S3 stores the raw decoded data